# Test for random distribution of values in a sequence

Tags: probability, distributions, entropy, information-theory, randomness

I'm looking to measure the degree to which values in a column or list are ordered or pseudo-randomly aligned. In essence I'm trying to distinguish the following scenarios.

Say we have a "sex" column filled with 50 "M" and 50 "F" values.

**Examples of "order":**

- If the data was sorted we would observe: *`F, F, F, .. M, M, M`* or vice versa.
- Similarly, there can be predictable patterns like: *`F, M, F, M, F, M`* or *`F, F, M, M, F, F, M, M`*

**Examples of randomness / randomly assigned positions to the values:**

- Any kind of white noise pattern.

Comment: Maybe the test statistic of the runs test [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test) could be a candidate.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.